# How add validation Email with pattern validation using ngClass

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I want to display data in red colour when email is invalid.

I have n no. of data, out of them some email ids are not validated.
I have used only dynamic class.

```
//ts file

email_regx = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

if (this.data.email_id) {
   this.email_regx = true;
} else {
  this.email_regx = false;
}

//html file
<span [ngClass]="{'redClass': email_regx}">{{ data?.email_id }}</span>

//css
  .redClass{ color: red}
```

Comment: `<input type="email" />` would be *so* much easier...

Comment: no i want only ngclass

Comment: why are you doing this `this.email_regx = true;`. You should do something like this. `this.data.email_id.test(this. email_regx)`

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using regex the right way. Have a look [to this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/test).

You can make a simple function to test your email and return a boolean.

Component ts file :

```
public isValidEmail(email: string): boolean {
    return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email);
}
```

html file :

```
<span [ngClass]="{'redClass': isValidEmail(data?.email_id)}">{{ data?.email_id }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, please think about using an input field instead.

I would recommend to use [**FormBuilder**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) from [*Angular Forms*](https://angular.io/guide/forms).
It will help you with a lean template and make validation a lot easier.

Could look like:

```
// TS
contactForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: [
            '',
            Validators.compose([
                Validators.pattern('^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$'),
                Validators.required,
            ])
        ]
    });
```

The FormGroup called "contactForm" here holds one input field called "email".
The validation is for your email.

```
// Template
<form id="contactForm" [formGroup]="contactForm">
    <ion-item lines="none" class="list-item">
        <div>
            <ion-label position="stacked"
                       [class.error]="contactForm.controls.email.value != undefined && !contactForm.controls.email.valid">
                E-Mail *
            </ion-label>
            <ion-input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

The important part here is the *formControlName* and the *[formGroup]* to connect to your ts´s validation.
The part *[class.error]* adds the class "error" to the label. You also could use that for your input field.